# Computing 2D contours from point cloud

Tags: algorithm, geometry, contour, point-clouds

I have a 2D point cloud, each carrying some scalar value. Assume that this value can be interpolated at any point on plane, and I have a degree of freedom to choose the exact interpolation formula, as long as it's smooth, and converges to the given points when calculated in their proximity.
My goal is to construct closed contours that correspond to constant scalar value.

My specific case is somewhat more complex, but for simplicity let's assume that we have a terrain elevation (height) sampled at some points, and we need to construct contours of constant elevation, for some given values of it. Contours should be approximated by polylines.

Previously I received the points in a form of a regular grid, and I solved it by examining and building (if necessary) contour segments in every grid cell separately. That is, for every grid cell I checked the values in corners to detect if the contour should cross cell boundaries (some corners should be higher and some lower), and calculated the intersection points respectively.

Now I need to reconstruct this from arbitrary point cloud.

Of course I can build a regular grid from the point cloud (since we know to interpolate), dense enough, from which the contours can be calculated, but I'd like a more efficient algorithm.
My idea is to connect the points in the cloud so that the plane is covered by triangles (or more complex convex polygons), each would form a grid cell. Then I can construct contours pretty much like I did before.

Is there a known algorithm to solve specifically this problem?

**Update:**

Thanks to @coproc. I'm aware of Delaunay triangulation, and this is probably the way to go.
There are still questions however about how to interpolate in arbitrary point on a plane: would it be sufficient to consider only the triangle vertexes, or also other nearby points. In an unballanced case there may be a situation where a point is in extreme proximity to the triangle. For example here:
[image: For example here]

As an alternative I can think of just starting from arbitrary point in a plane and then going perpendicular to the gradient to create the contours.

Comment: would a Delaunay triangulation help? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)

Comment: @coproc: thanks. Please see update

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a GIS interpolation/extrapolation issue. There are several techniques to interpolate more "intelligently" and I'd suggest you to try first inverse distance weighting (IDW) and then kriging if you have the time to pay attention to it.

IDW in short is based on the "first law of Geography": things close to each other tend to correlate. You give higher weights to closer points and interpolate the grid.

Kriging tries to take into consideration the directionality of the phenomena in question and adjusts the weights accordingly. Think of making a principal component analysis for the neighborhood and scaling point distances according to the variance in different directions.

This is a brief look at some of the existing methods.
http://www.bisolutions.us/A-Brief-Introduction-to-Spatial-Interpolation.php

Comment: Interpolation w.r.t. Weight = 1/R (or alternatively 1/R^n) sounds reasonable. However this means taking **all** the samples into account. Perhaps some cutoff criteria should be used

Comment: That is a reasonable assumption. The radius (or number of neighboring points) is a somewhat open question, so If your data processing time limit allows it, I'd suggest to play around with different radii. This should yield relatively good results but it all depends on your data and needs really. Alternatively you could try forming a semi-variogram of your data (z-value difference vs. xy-distance), fit a line/curve there and deduce the cutoff and perhaps non-linear distance weighting function. See here for more details http://gisgeography.com/semi-variogram-nugget-range-sill/

Comment: Ah, btw.. These techniques assume that you have somehow managed to capture the characteristic points of your surface, meaning the peaks and valley bottoms, edges. If your real world has higher peaks than your data they will be lost. Also if you use 1/R^n the farther points have virtually zero weights and won't contribute to the interpolation. However a large n might give a "polygonized" output since all points will get a value very similar to their closest point.